# JQuery DataTable clearing data after loading data with PHP

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4, datatable

Table is loaded with data but after some miliseconds datatable cleared the loaded data and a row comes with message "No matching records found"
[image]

```
HTML Code

<table id="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th><span class="table_header">Heading</span></th>
        <th><span class="table_header">Heading</span></th>
        <th><span class="table_header">Heading</span></th>
        <th><span class="table_header">Heading</span></th>
        <th><span class="table_header">Heading</span></th>
        <th><span class="table_header">Heading</span></th>
        <th><span class="table_header">Heading</span></th>
        <th><span class="table_header">Heading</span></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php get_data_from_db(); ?>
</tbody>
```

Where `get_data_from_db();` is afunction which is returning the rows in form of below.

```
$record = <<<DELIMETER 
<tr>   // Repeated with data    </tr>
DELIMETER;
echo $record;
```

Here is the Javascript Code

```
$('#table').DataTable();
```

Link DataTable files

```
<!-- Datatable css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/css/buttons.bootstrap4.min.css">
<!-- Datatable JS-->
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue

Comment: Can't tell from what I see. But please make sure, the html is generated properly, second see if `$.DataTable()` tries to initiate before the dom ready state. It needs to have the html rendered in order to work properly.

Comment: I verified the genrated html more the three but still getting same and the javascript code is in `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please verify that your tags have properly assigned with a unique ID not only the table but all of tags like input, label, select etc

Comment: Yes it works for me I gave all of my tags unique IDs